# How to time an input for CC2541?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to the BLE programming.

I am trying to read some sensor values, through a pressure based sensor. This needs to be done within a given time limit (say 5 s). I tried doing something with "osal_start_timerEx", but this seems to get to the event only after the timer expires.

Please advice on how this could be done.

After doing some reading though, I came up with the following code, but the for some reason, the sensors seem to have stopped working.

```
uint32 current_time = osal_GetSystemClock()
uint32 temp = current_time + 5000;
while (current_time != temp){
statSensor = ( statSensor1 & statSensor2 & statSensor3 & statSensor4 ); 
if (statSensor){
//this to do if the sensors are tapped within 5 seconds
break;
}
current_time = osal_GetSystemClock()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on what kind of pressure sensor is that and how do you want to read that information.

If you want to monitor continuously the pressure (eg the air pressure in a container) then you can setup a timer that reads the pressure only when there is a BLE connection to the device and notify the pressure every X seconds until the connection is dropped.

If you want to monitor the maximum pressure issued discretely (e.g. pressing with your finger and releasing) then you'd want to have a higher rate of reading the pressure, like every 50ms, and store the maximum pressure value. This should also be done only when there is a connection, this should help save battery if that's the case. You might want to send a command to the device to start measuring, allowing it a 5-10 sec timeout for reading the max pressure and then notify the stored value.

Comment: Actually, there seems to be a bit of mis-understanding. I am trying to perform an actuation if the sensor has been tapped within 5 seconds. If not tapped within 5 seconds, no actuation is to be performed.

Comment: You need to determine a context for the start of the _within 5 seconds_ interval that you can transform that in code on your CC2541. For example, have a slow timer that reads the pressure every 100ms-1000ms, depending on the speed of the pressure event, to detect change in pressure value. If change is detected, then increase the reading frequency for 5 seconds to detect the peak pressure that should go over the threshold pressure that should trigger the event. If within those 5 seconds the max pressure went over the threshold, perform the actuation.